# Counting Distinct Months with Multiple records per month

Tags: sql

My data looks like this:

```
Code    Date
123     1/2/2016
123     1/4/2016 
123     1/4/2016
123     2/5/2016
456     1/2/2016
456     1/3/2016
456     2/7/2016
789     1/7/2016
789     1/8/2016
789     3/7/2016
789     3/15/2016
```

I am looking for a distinct count of months grouped by the code.

So the results would look something like this

```
Code     Jan2016      Feb2016      Mar2016
123         1           1            0
456         1           1            0
789         1           0            1
```

I feel like I may be overcomplicating my code.

So far I have

```
SELECT
    p.code
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN p.date BETWEEN '11/1/2010' AND '11/30/2010' 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov2010'
    FROM table
    Group By p.code
```

But that is pulling in all records from Nov2010, when I just need to know if this exists

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your aggregate function. Use `MAX` instead of `SUM`.

```
SELECT
  p.code
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN p.date BETWEEN '11/1/2010' AND '11/30/2010' 
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov2010'
FROM table
Group By p.code
```

Comment: Will using MAX work if there is a duplicate MAX date within the month itself?

Comment: @baineschile the `MAX` is being applied to the `CASE` not to the date column. The `MAX` function will return 1 if there is at least a row within that month, and 0 otherwise. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thats what I want. But if there are two records with the same max date (ie 12/13/2016) wont that be counted twice?

Comment: @baineschile No, it should do exactly what you want. Give it a try and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 0):

in SQL Server you can use a pivot table, bit messy but something like this will work, sample data:

```
declare @table table (code int, date date)
insert into @table values 
(123, '1/2/2016'),
(123, '1/4/2016'),
(123, '1/4/2016'),
(123, '2/5/2016'),
(456, '1/2/2016'),
(456, '1/3/2016'),
(456, '2/7/2016'),
(789, '1/7/2016'),
(789, '1/8/2016'),
(789, '3/7/2016'),
(789, '3/15/2016')
```

then using a pivot table:

```
with cte (code) as (select distinct code from @table)

select  
    c1.code,
    ISNULL(months.[1],0) as 'Jan 2016',
    ISNULL(months.[2],0) as 'Feb 2016',
    ISNULL(months.[3],0) as 'Mar 2016'
from 
   (
    select
    c.code,
    count( distinct t.code) as [ID],
    month(date) as [month]
    from @table t
    join cte c on t.code = c.code
    group by c.code, month(date)
    ) P
pivot 
    (
    sum([ID])
    for [month] IN ("1","2","3")--,"4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12")
    ) as months
    join cte c1 on months.code = c1.code
```

will give you the following results:

```
code    Jan 2016    Feb 2016    Mar 2016
123         1          1           0
456         1          1           0
789         1          0           1
```

If you take the comment out after the 3rd month you can do it for the rest of the year

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but this wont work. I have a few million rows to look at. I was just giving a basic example for context.

Comment: @baineschile it will do the same logic with any amount of rows, i just showed the sample data as i was using temp tables in the query

Comment: just change 'from @table' in the query to your table name, take the comment out the pivot table to get the rest of the months and add them rest into the select